# Baffling Pythagoras Theorem Question

Tags: pythagorean-triples

I came across this question. I asked my math teacher and the whole class yet no one came up with an answer. Could one of you try it? (The answers in the book say 3√2)

[image]

Comment: If $P$ is a point in the plane of rectangle $ABCD$ then $AP^2+CP^2=BP^2+DP^2$.

Comment: To explain the previous comment let $P=(x,y).$  Let $A=(0,0), B=(0, h),C=(l,h), D=(l,0).$ Then $AP^2+CP^2=$ $ (\;x^2+y^2\;)+(\;(x-l)^2+ (y-h)^2\;)$ while  $BP^2+DP^2=$ $(\; x^2+(y-h)^2\;)+(\;(x-l)^2+y^2\;).$